# How would one split the data in a column of an unstuctured format and put it back into structured a structured form?

Tags: powerquery

The issue I am dealing with basically has a field for 2 types of data (SERIAL_NO) and (EXP_DATE) and a third field for unstructured data entry (COMMENTS). Additional information is placed in the unstructured data field that I need to turn into structured data.

| OPER_KEY | TIME_STAMP | SERIAL_NO | EXP_DATE | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35374 | 1/12/2021 11:30 | M161001 | 10/31/2021 | M190426, 5/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/8/2021 13:59 | M161001 | 10/31/2021 | M190426 , 5/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/25/2021 15:32 | M190426 | 5/31/2021 | M161001, EXP 10/31/21 |
| 35413 | 9/13/2019 16:21 | M151144 | 11/30/2019 | EXAMPLE TEXT |
| 35413 | 9/12/2019 11:44 | M15144 | 11/30/2019 |  |
| 35413 | 9/14/2019 12:15 | M190426 | 4/30/2020 | M151144 M190426 |
| 35058 | 1/14/2019 8:53 | M180117 | 1/31/2019 | E190426 5/31/2021 M161001 10/31/21 |

There are no easy delimiters. The format is, the first letter is a character, followed by 6 digits. Then sometimes followed by a date. These need to be merged back into the original table like so.

| OPER_KEY | TIME_STAMP | SERIAL_NO | EXP_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35374 | 1/12/2021 11:30 | M161001 | 10/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/12/2021 11:30 | M190426 | 5/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/8/2021 13:59 | M161001 | 10/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/8/2021 13:59 | M190426 | 5/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/25/2021 15:32 | M190426 | 5/31/2021 |
| 35374 | 1/25/2021 15:32 | M161001 | 10/31/21 |
| 35413 | 9/13/2019 16:21 | M151144 | 11/30/2019 |
| 35413 | 9/12/2019 11:44 | M15144 | 11/30/2019 |
| 35413 | 9/14/2019 12:15 | M190426 | 4/30/2020 |
| 35413 | 9/14/2019 12:15 | M151144 |  |
| 35413 | 9/14/2019 12:15 | M190426 |  |
| 35058 | 1/14/2019 8:53 | M180117 | 1/31/2019 |
| 35058 | 1/14/2019 8:53 | E190426 | 5/31/2021 |
| 35058 | 1/14/2019 8:53 | M161001 | 10/31/21 |

I can reference the original table and then group the section by "all rows" immediately to work with the data and later append the original table with the new data. The issue I am having is how to successfully parse out the relevant data into columns. Any recommendations on how to extract this information?

Comment: I'll ask the same question again.  There is a sequence, sometimes it looks like it is followed with (space)(comma)(space), sometimes with (comma)(space) sometimes with nothing; and sometimes the data has (date) while other time it has (EXP)(date). Is that right?

Comment: The commonality is there is the letter followed by at least 5 digits and often but not always proceeded by a date. The date also tends to be in various formats. The "comments" section is just a text field where additional data was entered without any kind of formatting. Some tend to follow some consistent formatting but it can be all over the place, hence the data being unstructured. The multiple data lines at the bottom of the example will always have a next line character to split the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that works on your data example: *read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm:*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"OPER_KEY", Int64.Type}, {"TIME_STAMP", type datetime}, {"SERIAL_NO", type text}, {"EXP_DATE", type date}, {"COMMENTS", type text}}),

//Create list of Serial numbers from the Comments Column    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Comment SN", each if [COMMENTS] = null then {null} else 
            let 
                #"Split Text" = List.RemoveItems(Text.SplitAny([COMMENTS],", #(lf)"),{""}),
                #"Serial Nos" = List.Transform(
                                    List.Select(
                                      List.Transform(#"Split Text", (li)=>Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"A".."Z","a".."z"}, {"0".."9"})(li)), 
                                    each List.Count(_)=2),
                                each Text.Combine(_,""))
            in 
                #"Serial Nos", type list),

//Create list of dates from the Comments column
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Comments Dates", each if [COMMENTS] = null then {null} else 
            let 
                #"Split Text" = List.RemoveItems(Text.SplitAny([COMMENTS],", #(lf)"),{""}),
                Dates =  List.Select(#"Split Text", (li)=> Record.Field(try Date.From(li), "HasError")=false)
            in 
                Dates, type list),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.Buffer(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"COMMENTS"})),

//create the results table
//First row is from the first four columns
//For subsequent rows we extract the corresponding SN and Date from the Comments column
    #"Add Result Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns","Result", (tr)=> 
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[r=Record.FromList({tr[OPER_KEY],tr[TIME_STAMP],tr[SERIAL_NO],tr[EXP_DATE]},{"OPER_KEY","TIME_STAMP","SERIAL_NO","EXP_DATE"}), idx=0]    ,
            each [idx] <= List.Count(tr[Comment SN]),
            each [r=Record.FromList({null, null, tr[Comment SN]{[idx]}, try tr[Comments Dates]{[idx]} otherwise null},{"OPER_KEY","TIME_STAMP","SERIAL_NO","EXP_DATE"}), idx=[idx]+1],
            each [r] 
        ) ),

//Remove all the columns except Results
//and expand
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Result Column",{"OPER_KEY", "TIME_STAMP", "SERIAL_NO", "EXP_DATE", "Comment SN", "Comments Dates"}),
    #"Expanded Result" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Result"),
    #"Expanded Result1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Result", "Result", {"OPER_KEY", "TIME_STAMP", "SERIAL_NO", "EXP_DATE"}, {"OPER_KEY", "TIME_STAMP", "SERIAL_NO", "EXP_DATE"}),

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Result1",{{"OPER_KEY", Int64.Type}, {"TIME_STAMP", type datetime}, {"SERIAL_NO", type text}, {"EXP_DATE", type date}}),

    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Blank Rows",{"OPER_KEY", "TIME_STAMP"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

[image]